# How to put numeric vector into function instead of character in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame:

```
gr <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1)
x <- c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
y <- c(20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25)
z <- c(30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35)
data <- data.frame(gr, x, y, z)
```

I would like to perform a `t.test` of all variables in my data frame. To do that I wrote a function

```
t_test <- function(var){
  p <- t.test(var ~ gr)$p.value
  t <- t.test(var ~ gr)$statistic
  
  if (p < 0.05) {
    des <- 'good'
  } else { des <- 'bad'}
  
  out <- list(p, t, des)
  return(out)
}
```

And then I'd like to perform `t.test`.

What I figured out is that if I put name of column into function, the function doesn't work. For example

```
t_test('x')
```

In this case an error occurs. But when I run the following code

```
t_test(x)
```

i.e. without quotes everything works well.

How to resolve this problem?
This is very important because I have a data frame with 80 columns and I need to perform this test in loop like this:

```
data_colnames <- names(data)[2:ncol(data)]
t_test_data <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 0))
names(t_test_data) <- c("variable", "t_stat", "p_value", "decision")

for (i in 1:length(data_colnames)){
  t_test_data[i,  'variable'] <-  data_colnames[i]
  t_test_data[i, 't_stat']  <- t_test(data_colnames[i])[2]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative how you could achieve your task:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
data %>% 
    mutate(gr = as.character(gr)) %>% 
    select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
    map_df(~ tidy(t.test(. ~ gr)), .id = 'var') %>% 
    select(var, statistic, p.value) %>% 
    mutate(decision = ifelse(p.value < 0.05, "good", "bad"))
```

```
  var   statistic p.value decision
  <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   
1 x         -1.87   0.135 bad     
2 y         -1.87   0.135 bad     
3 z         -1.87   0.135 bad
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `paste` or `reformulate` to create the formula from a string input.  In the OP's code, two times the model was build to access the 'p.value' and 'statistic'.  Instead, build the model once and extract the components by assinging it to an object ('tmodel')

```
t_test <- function(var){
  tmodel <- t.test(reformulate("gr", response = var))
  p <- tmodel$p.value
  t <- tmodel$statistic
  
  if (p < 0.05) {
    des <- 'good'
  } else { des <- 'bad'}
  
  out <- list(t, p, des)
  return(out)
}
```

-testing

```
> t_test("x")
[[1]]
        t 
-1.870829 

[[2]]
[1] 0.1347019

[[3]]
[1] "bad"
```

---

For multiple cases, do

```
> sapply(data_colnames, \(x) setNames(t_test(x), names(t_test_data)[-1]))
               x         y         z        
t_stat   -1.870829 -1.870829 0.1492787
p_value  0.1347019 0.1347019 0.8931025
decision "bad"     "bad"     "bad"
```

---

Or using the OP's `for` loop

```
for (i in seq_along(data_colnames)){ 
    t_test_data[i,  'variable'] <-  data_colnames[i]
   t_test_data[i, -1] <- t_test(data_colnames[i])
 }
```

-output

```
> t_test_data
  variable     t_stat   p_value decision
1        x -1.8708287 0.1347019      bad
2        y -1.8708287 0.1347019      bad
3        z  0.1492787 0.8931025      bad
```